# Time Complexity of python's deque.Insert(index,element)

Tags: python-3.x

```
from collections import deque
d = deque("dbkd")
d.insert(2,"h")
```

What is the time complexity of `d.insert(2,"h")`   ?
If deque is implemented as a linked list then it should be `O(1)`? Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#deque-objects

Literally in the docs. O(n) time complexity.

Comment: Where mention O(n)?

Comment: @Voyager Presumably they referred to the statement that "Indexed access is O(1) at both ends but slows to O(n) in the middle" below the documentation for the methods.

Comment: "Though list objects support similar operations, they are optimized for fast fixed-length operations and incur O(n) memory movement costs for pop(0) and insert(0, v) operations which change both the size and position of the underlying data representation."

Comment: @AlexOh that's talking about `list` objects not `deque` objects